# Receiving UDP packets from different network interfaces

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, networking, serversocket

Dears,

I would grateful if  you can guide me to solve this problem.

Firstly, let me introduce the scenario.

The scenario is:
- one device with two network interfaces as the sender.
- one device with two network interfaces as the receiver.

We are trying to emulate a mobile device that is able to receive packets from mobile networks (4G, for example) and wifi networks.

The communication must be done using UDP sockets.

The sender sends packets randomly through both interfaces (not in parallel).
The receiver must be prepared to receive packets from each interfaces

There are two UDP sockets for both receiver and sender. Each UDP socket is assigned for a different loopback interface (127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2) and have the same port number (different IPs, same port number).

The sockaddr_in structure is serverAddr:

```
serverAddr[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
serverAddr[i].sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
serverAddr[i].sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);
setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &enable, sizeof(int));
```

The receiver has two threads blocked in the recvfrom method. By the time the program starts, both threads are waiting packets. No matter which client interface sends the first packet, from the second packet on, every new packet seems to be received by the 127.0.0.1 interface. I know that INADDR_ANY allows to receive packets destined to any of the interfaces.

My doubts are: Why packets are not being received at the 127.0.0.2 interface anymore? What will be the correct approach to listen packets incomming from different network interfaces?

server side code:

```
struct info {
    int socketDescriptor;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    unsigned int size;
};


int udpEchoServer();
void *connection_handler(void *socketInfo);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    udpEchoServer();

    puts("Press any key to continue");
    getc(stdin);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}



int udpEchoServer()
{
    int socketFileDescriptor[NUM_CONNECTIONS], enable = 1, client_sock;
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr[NUM_CONNECTIONS];
    //struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    info socketInfo[NUM_CONNECTIONS];
    pthread_t thread[NUM_CONNECTIONS];
    const char* interfaces[] = {"127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.2"};

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CONNECTIONS; i++){
        socketFileDescriptor[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        if(socketFileDescriptor[i] == -1) {
            perror("Error on socket creation\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        if (setsockopt(socketFileDescriptor[i], SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enable, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            printf("setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed");

        bzero(&serverAddr[i], sizeof(serverAddr[i]));

        serverAddr[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
        serverAddr[i].sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        serverAddr[i].sin_port = htons(PORTNUM);

        if (bind(socketFileDescriptor[i], (struct sockaddr*)& serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr)) == -1) {
            close(socketFileDescriptor[i]);
            perror("bind failed socket\n");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }


        printf("Socket #%d listening\n", socketFileDescriptor[i]);



        socketInfo[i].socketDescriptor = socketFileDescriptor[i];
        socketInfo[i].addr = serverAddr[i];
        socketInfo[i].size = sizeof(serverAddr[i]);
    }



    printf("Waiting incomming!!\n");
    int nThreads = 0;


    while (nThreads < NUM_CONNECTIONS)
    {


        printf("++++++ Creating reception thread %d\n", nThreads);
        if( pthread_create( &thread[nThreads] , NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &socketInfo[nThreads]) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        sleep(1);
        /
        printf("nThreads = %d\n", nThreads++);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_CONNECTIONS; i++) {
        pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
    }



    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void *connection_handler(void *socketInfo)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    info *newSocketInfo = (info*)socketInfo;
    int n;//, local_sock;
    char clientname[200];
    pthread_t self_id;
    self_id=pthread_self();

    while (true) {
        printf("=========> Waiting connection in thread #%u\n", self_id);
        printf("newSocketInfo->socketDescriptor = %d\n", newSocketInfo->socketDescriptor);
        printf("Adress = %s\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET,&newSocketInfo->addr.sin_addr, clientname, sizeof(clientname)));



        char client_message[2000];

        printf("Waiting packets\n");

        n = recvfrom(newSocketInfo->socketDescriptor, client_message, sizeof(client_message), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&newSocketInfo->addr, &newSocketInfo->size);

        sleep(1);
        printf("++ %d Bytes received at %d. Sending it back\n", n, newSocketInfo->socketDescriptor);
        sendto(newSocketInfo->socketDescriptor,client_message,n,0, (struct sockaddr *)&newSocketInfo->addr, newSocketInfo->size);

        if(n==0) {
            puts("Client Disconnected");
        } else if (n > 0) {
            puts("recvfrom ok");
        } else {
            perror("read failed");
        }
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `accept` on a UDP socket?  That's only used for stream connections (e.g. TCP) to hand off a per-connection socket for each connected client that has attached to the `listen`ing socket.

Comment: (you shouldn't be calling `listen` either)

Comment: also, the description of your network setup appears incomplete. If the 127.* addresses are on virtual loopback interfaces, how does the other machine know how to reach them?

Comment: @Alnitak You're being kind. Every address in the 127.0.0.0/8 address block is a loopback address and can't be reached from outside the machine.

Comment: @AndrewHenle indeed.  It's not unheard of to put real addresses onto a loopback interface and then use a routing protocol to advertise them, but I'm pretty sure that's not what's happening here.

Comment: also `SO_REUSEPORT` isn't required either - on Linux, at least, that's only needed if the same port is to be bound on multiple sockets on the same IP address.

Comment: hmph - the 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2 strings in the `interfaces` array aren't even being used in this code...

Comment: I've just deleted accept and listen. ( you are right they are for TCP).  I had interfaces array  just to check and they are not used. However, the problem exists.